# ¿Como puedo integrar una base de datos realm a mi apk?

Tags: android

```
@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();

    setUpRealmConfig();

    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    BoardId = getIdByTable(realm, Board.class);
    NoteID = getIdByTable(realm, Note.class);
    realm.close();
}

private void setUpRealmConfig()
{
    RealmConfiguration configuration = new RealmConfiguration
            .Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .name("ucf_database.realm")
            .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
            .build();
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(configuration);
}
```

Hay alguna forma de que en el builder darle el camino a la base de datos y el la copie cuando se instala? Cualquier ayuda es agradecida.

Comment: Consulta usas gradle??

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con "el builder"?

Comment: Me refiero a RealmConfiguration.Builder(), recibe un context y puede recibir un file, yo lo que quiero saber es que si hay alguna forma que de que al instalar la apk la base de datos este adentro de ella sin necesidad de creerla una vez instalada la apk. Lo hice una vez y la guarde y lo q hago es copiarla cada vez que instalo la apk y es pesado pero no la puedo distribuir porque los datos se copian en la raiz yo tengo acceso porque mi terminal esta rooteado pero no todos tienen root en el telefono. Espero haberme explicado bien. Espero su ayuda @RaulCacacho uso gradle porque?

Comment: YA lo logre, solo tuve que crear una carpeta assets y poner la base de datos creada adentro y luego decirle al realmConfiguration  .assetFile(context, [name of the assets file]);